# PyPI Python Version wrong

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to upload a python package. It seems that there is a discrepancy between the Python version specified in the package and the Requires: Python on PyPI.

The package is this one: https://pypi.org/project/metisfl/

PyPI says that it requires Python 3.8 but the wheel are for python 3.9-3.10. When trying to install from a 3.9 or 3.10 it fails, as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to deploy to TestPyPI first if you're not sure your release procedure is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Your `setup.py` has pretty funky determination for the package version that entirely depends on the *running interpreter*](https://github.com/NevronAI/MetisFL/blob/8d625a4cf01a83e2e9a7ff6f6c201542cbf67bbd/setup.py#L27-L33).

Just do

```
python_requires=">=3.8",
```

without additional magic, and you should be good.

Also, there's a typo on the next line: `pltforms`...

You might also consider using `hatch`/`hatchling` or something else instead of old-school `setup.py` files.